# MVC additional model relations

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am trying to learn the natives of MVC and for this purpose i am creating an application which uses this pattern!

Now as far as i understand the M (Model) is to be thought of as the database link. This link is related to ONE table in the database. For instance a `User` table in the database is a `User` model in the code. Meaning that anything that has to do with the `User table` is done through the `User Model`.

Now in many applications it is required to show data in a V (`View`) from different database tables.

My question is.

If the data that needs to be shown does not have a relation between eachother (for instance `users` and `products`) where should the "double `model` data collectiong" happen? as far as i can understand the `Controllers` should be as slim as possible. But they should also work as a binding component with a model and a view.

So if a `view` requires data from more than one `model` should the `controller` do the work or should the `model` do the work?

Its abit tricky to full describe what i mean but i hope you get the idea.

Also if any of the above statements is incorrect please correct me.

Comment: Look, the main point is that your first assumption is not quite accurate. There is no mandatory relationship (one-on-one or any other) between Model classes and database tables. The Model's classes should be "units" (or "things") that have meaning to your business, not tables (see [Anemic Domain Model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)). So if you have a relation between `users` and `products` that is meaningful to your business, there should be a mecanism (probably a class) in the model/domain that handles that, even if there is no table with that name.

Answer (score -1):

In general the `controller` is responsible to collect data to the `view`, consider the opportunity to create a `ViewModel` that collect the different data to be displaied and that is populated by the `controller`.

This is the case when you have to display the given model in a complex way or you have aggregated data or master-details views.

But in the case your needs arises from a different vision of a given model from the perspective of the application you are developing, consider the opportunity to map that model to an `application data model` that reflects better the `application domain`.

In this case you add a layer that do the work of creating a `model` that better reflects the application point of view, then the `controller` do the actions to perform on it.

Comment: -1: please see "component interactions" section in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller